# Lubridate - how to properly parse decimal minutes using parse_date_time

Tags: r, lubridate

Let's say that you have a vector of times in minutes stored as decimal numbers. For this example, I am going to pick 2.5, which means 2 minutes and 30 seconds.

I want to parse this using `lubridate`'s `parse_date_time` function. However, the output I see is wrong. After running this line:

```
parse_date_time(2.5, "M:S")
```

I am getting the following output:

```
"0000-01-01 00:02:05 UTC"
```

Instead of expected

```
"0000-01-01 00:02:30 UTC"
```

Somehow lubridate doesn't recognize that my `.5` doesn't mean 5 seconds, but 30 seconds since two and a half minutes are 2 minutes and 30 seconds and not 2 minutes and 5 seconds.

What is the proper format of the `parse_date_time` I should use to get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use `lubridate` you can do something like this

```
library(lubridate)
time <- 2.5
as.period(as.duration(days(x=1))*(time/24))
#[1] "2H 30M 0S"
as.period(as.duration(days(x=1))*(time/1440))
#[1] "2M 30S"
```

Comment: Thanks but I need 0 H 2 MIN 30 S

Comment: Then you can change from `24` hour in a day to `1440` minutes in a day.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base R option :

```
val <- 2.5
as.POSIXct(val*60, origin = '0000-01-01', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "0000-01-01 00:02:30 UTC"
```